# sequence of values from line in file in bash

Tags: bash, line, sequence

I do have file which contains the following:

```
id=123
time=1440367263
from=user1
version=none
final=none
id=124
time=1440367264
from=user2
version=none
final=none
etc...
```

However, sometime line as "from" or "final" are missing, which break the sequence.
example:

```
id=123
time=1440367263
from=user1
version=none
final=none
id=124
time=1440367264
version=none
final=none
etc...
```

the matter is, I am trying to generate single line from it,  from the example 1, the output that I am generating is the following:

```
id=123 time=1440367263 from=user1 version=none final=none
id=124 time=1440367264 from=user2 version=none final=none
```

if some values are missing, then it breaks the order for each line.
id, time, from, version, final

How could I maintain these order and if there is a missing value add it with =0 value in order to keep the sequence?

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,
AL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
awk -F= '
    function report() {
        printf("id=%s time=%s from=%s version=%s final=%s\n",
               a["id"], a["time"], a["from"], a["final"])
    }
    function reset() {
        # Make sure the array a is empty
        delete a
        # Defining the fields in which we are interested
        a["id"]=a["time"]=a["from"]=a["version"]=a["final"]=0
    }
    $1=="id" {
         if ("id" in a) report()
         reset()
    }
    $1 in a {a[$1]=$2} # Storing key + value 
                       # if we are interested in a field
' file
```

EDIT: Reworked, as I understand the requirements now :)

Comment: Hi, thank for the awk functions. however i am having this error while trying it..     awk: cmd. line:17: }
    awk: cmd. line:17: ^ syntax error

Comment: Hi Joepd, thank you very much. However and since I have started indeed to look into the source file as why such of entries are missing.... Big thank you and you seems to know really well awk :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please consider ot accept and/or upvote answers that bring you further.

Answer (score 0):

there is no magic one-line solution for that, you'll need to create a custom script, something like:

- reset 5 variables (for id, time, from, version and final) to value `0`
- read lines from file until you read the line starting with "final" (supposing final is always present...).
- when you read the lines, fill the corresponding variables
- finally print the line with the variables you read

and loop over this until the end of your file.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose `id` is always present, i inject a newline before it

```
cat r |tr '\n' ' '|sed -r 's/(id=[^ ]+)/\n\1/g';echo
```

output

```
id=123 time=1440367263 from=user1 version=none final=none 
id=124 time=1440367264 version=none final=none
```